# Linux Mint: audio slows down opening apps while playing video

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, usb-device

I'm using focusrite 2i2 USB audio interface on my Mint 20 machine. While playing a movie if I go and start another application especially if it has something to do with audio (e.g.: OBS, telegram desktop,...) audio clicks a few times and for the rest of video it slows down by ~20%. To correct it I need to run

```
pulseaudio -k
```

I did the tsched=0 trick in pulseaudio but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 20.04. Same issue